# How to delete page by deactivating plugin

Tags: plugins, pages

```
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );

function myplugin_activate() {

   //create a variable to specify the details of page

   $post = array(     

             'post_content'   => 'content', //content of page

             'post_title'     =>'Auto Page by activating plugin', //title of page
             'post_status'    =>  'publish' , //status of page - publish or draft
             'post_type'      =>  'page'  // type of post
   );

   wp_insert_post( $post ); // creates page
```

Above code is for creating page by activating plugin.

How to delete page by deactivating plugin?

Comment: it's not great to auto-create things like this, it's better to prompt the user. Also, what happens if the user renames the page or already has a page with that name?

Answer (score -3):

```php
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,'dropPage');

function dropPage(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("delete from ".$wpdb->prefix ."post where post_name = 'custom creation'");
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Can you update it to explain how it solves the question and what the missing information was? Also that SQL query doesn't check the post type or other things and could destroy unrelated information that just happens to have the same slug/title.

Comment: Your answer is off to a great start. To truly make it a lasting resource, can you edit to also explain how it answers the question? That way we self-learners can benefit from your answer all the more.